# Why do elements stop displaying for no apparent reason?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi I am an IOS novice trying to work on a table view with detail app.  I am using a brand new macbook air and Xcode 6.  However, I keep notice things inexplicably disappearing or going wrong in display of build.  I tried cleaning to no avail.

I did not change the code below for a table displaying subview and an image on the right but now only the head is displaying, no longer the subhead or either of the pictures, the standard one in subview and the right image I added.  Is the program just buggy or did something creep into my code without my noticing?

The only thing I did do is in a separate detail controller, added an image outlet property and another property neither of which throws a warning but why would this mess up the tableviewcontroller scene?

Here is code for table that was working but now is not displaying subtext or images though it is displaying head:

```
static NSString *protoCell = @"Cell";
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:protoCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"head";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"sub";

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
    UIImageView *rightimage;
    rightimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0,0.0,80.0,45.0)];
    rightimage.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];
    rightimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];

    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0;
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 50);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: "Here is code for table that was working but now is not displaying subtext or images though it is displaying head" So debug it. Roll the project back to its state before you made this change. Or comment out new code until you figure out what difference is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you ever remove the `rightimage` from your cell's content view?  If not, you'll be adding another of them each time a cell is reused.  I'm not sure it has anything to do with your problem but it's a potential bug and a potential memory drain.

Comment: Do not say "no apparent reason". There is a clear and simple reason. It just isn't apparent to _you_.

Comment: Just reading the title I could tell that you don't understand the concept of "cell recycling" in UITableView.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many issues. The main one is that you are forgetting about cell reuse. You are saying

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];
```

for *every* call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. But this is called many times for the *same* cell, because cells are reused. So if you have 100 rows in your table, you can end up with 100 (or 1000, or 10000) copies of `rightImage` in the same cell.

Also, you are saying this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"head";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"sub";
[cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage]; // ???
```

You should not be mixing the built-in `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` with your own additional subviews.

So basically the takeaway message is: if you want to customize the contents of a cell, instead of just using the built-in `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`, then you need to stop and go back and learn how to do that.

Oh, and one more thing. You say:

> I keep notice things inexplicably disappearing or going wrong in display of build

No. Stop. Things do not inexplicably happen. You will not learn to program if you suspect mysterious forces of sneaking in and messing things up, like cosmic rays. If your code breaks, *you* broke it. Learn to face the fact that if your code does not behave as you expect, *you* are doing something wrong. You will never be a good programmer unless you come to terms with that way of thinking.